# How to write a Python code for downloading an abstract from PubMed?

Tags: python-3.x, download, pubmed, ncbi

This is the code I have as of now and I have tried multiple different ways to get the correct code but to no avail.

I am using the Biopython module for this.

```
from Bio.Entrez import efetch

def print_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')
    print handle.read()
```

I tried the code as listed above along with a few tweaks here and there but nothing seems to be working for a simple query.

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What document do you get back?

Comment: Your usage of the `print` statement instead of the `print()` function indicates that you're using python 2, not python 3 (which is what you tagged your question with).  Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] for _your specific problem_. Also remember that your question's title must _summarize your question_, not tell us what the overall objective of your code is. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: When using python3, use `print()` as such:

```py
from Bio.Entrez import efetch
 
def print_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')
    print(handle.read())
```

Step 2: To make use of NCBI's E-utilities, NCBI requires you to specify your email address with each request. So, specify any email (it doesn't have to be real) as follows:

```py
from Bio import Entrez                                                                                                                                                                                          
Entrez.email = 'some@example.com'
```

Step 3: Now you can retrieve an abstract programmatically, for example by running

```py
print_abstract(35312860)
```

This gives me:

```
1. Acta Diabetol. 2022 Mar 21. doi: 10.1007/s00592-022-01878-z. [Epub ahead of 
print]                                                                                                   
                                                                                                         
Significant and persistent improvements in time in range and positive emotions in
children and adolescents with type 1 diabetes using a closed-loop control system 
after attending a virtual educational camp.                                                              
...
OBJECTIVE: To evaluate the six-month impact of the advanced automated functions...
```